# Mysql return 0 on non existing dates

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This is the query in which im interested to get a 0 if there are no results by specified calldate.

```
SELECT ifnull(count(*),0),
     FROM `cdr2015`  
        WHERE dst in ('602','603','605')  
     AND ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-04-20' ,0)
     AND disposition = 'NO ANSWER' 
     AND ((WEEKDAY(calldate) > 4) 
     OR 
     (WEEKDAY(calldate) < 5)  
     AND ((ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%T') >= '20:01:00',0))
     OR (ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%T') <= '07:59:00',0)))) 
     GROUP BY dst;
```

Is there any way to get 0 on non existing field `calldate`? This is the code that gives me problems `AND ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-04-20' ,0)`. Cant find a way of getting 0 on the count(*), i cant use another table to do an inner join of the DST field...

DATA SAMPLE

QUERY

```
        SELECT ifnull(count(*),0) as test
     FROM `cdr2015`  
        WHERE dst in ('602','603','605')  
     AND disposition = 'NO ANSWER' 
     AND ((WEEKDAY(calldate) > 4) 
     OR 
     (WEEKDAY(calldate) < 5)  
     AND ((ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%T') >= '20:01:00',0))
     OR (ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%T') <= '07:59:00',0)))) 
     GROUP BY dst;
```

OUTPUT:

```
 test
 25
 30
 50
```

QUERY:

```
     SELECT ifnull(count(*),0) AS test
     FROM `cdr2015`  
        WHERE dst in ('602','603','605')  
     AND ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-03-29' ,0)
     AND disposition = 'NO ANSWER' 
     AND ((WEEKDAY(calldate) > 4) 
     OR 
     (WEEKDAY(calldate) < 5)  
     AND ((ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%T') >= '20:01:00',0))
     OR (ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%T') <= '07:59:00',0)))) 
     GROUP BY dst;
```

OUTPUT: nothing...

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you're asking. Can you show sample data, expected results, and current results? ifnull(count(*), 0) makes no sense.

Comment: @Neville K just updated

Comment: What do you expect to do with this statement: `(WEEKDAY(calldate) > 4) OR (WEEKDAY(calldate) < 5)`? Weekday values are [0-6] (integer, day index).

Answer (score 0):

Data has to exists to get a zero (or any value) in return. So you will not be able to get that result. However with the COUNT(*) it will return a record saying "0" as result anyway found, so once you correct some of the brackets in your query you can get the result you are looking for.

Your query is a bit buggy with the brackets.

Fix all lines where your brackets our off.For example:

Your code:

```
SELECT ifnull(count(*),0),
 FROM `cdr2015`  
    WHERE dst in ('602','603','605')  
 AND ifnull(DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-04-20' ,0)
```

Might work a lot better if you did this:

```
SELECT count(*)
 FROM `cdr2015`  
    WHERE dst in ('602','603','605')  
 AND DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-04-20'
```

The IFNULL was around the complete AND in the where clause. This would never work.

The count(*) will always return an integer, so no IFNULL statement is required there.

Your other IFNULL statements also need corrections (For educational purposes you can do that yourself).